# Kubernetes authorization via local groups

Tags: linux, kubernetes, authorization, rbac

everyone.

I'm wondering is there an option to authorize users to access kubernetes objects via local groups?

Like currently I'm doing this:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example-rolebinding
  namespace: mynamespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: example-user1 # member of local unix group "authorized"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
- kind: User
  name: example-user2 # member of local unix group "authorized"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
- kind: User
  name: example-user3 # member of local unix group "authorized"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: example-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

And I am trying to do it this way:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example-rolebinding
  namespace: mynamespace
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: authorized
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: example-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Is there any option? Or I want too much from K8S and need to develop something on my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Groups are kind of an opaque construct between the authentication layer and the rbac system. Whichever authn plugin you are using can tag the request with a username and any number of groups, and then rbac will use them. But k8s itself doesn’t know what a user or group really is. So tldr it’s up to your authn configuration and plugin.